# Javascript how to loop child element of children

Tags: javascript, children

I want to read an element's children and for each of the children, read their children.

I have done this but do not understand why it does not work:

```
var myElement = $('.a-container');
var myChildren = myElement.children();

for(var i = 0; i < myChildren.length; i++) {
     var myGrandChildren = myChildren[i].children();
}
```

The error I get is `myChildren[i].children()` is not a function.

Is this not how to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Without getting a runnable sample of your code it would be hard to tell. `$('.a-container').children().children()` should work, but I am not sure what the type of your `myChildren` var is. If not then you need to `$()` wrap your var (edit: what @Spectric said should work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select the element inside the loop:

```js
myGrandChildren = $(myChildren[i]).children();
```

Although in this case, [`jQuery.eq`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) is more suitable:

```js
myGrandChildren = myChildren.eq(i).children();
```

Comment: the .get didn't work, but the first did.